# How does Java know that RuntimeExceptions are unchecked?

Tags: java, exception

How does the Java compiler know that `java.lang.RuntimeException` and its subclasses are unchecked, since they inherit from `java.lang.Exception`, which is a checked exception? I looked into the code and doesn't seem to be anything inside the class that tells it to the compiler.

Comment: Because it 'knows' what's written in the JLS, not just what's in the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it is defined that way in the [specification of the language # 11.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1-300):

> - The unchecked exception classes are the runtime exception classes and the error classes.
> - The checked exception classes are all exception classes other than the unchecked exception classes. That is, the checked exception classes are all subclasses of Throwable other than RuntimeException and its subclasses and Error and its subclasses.

So it is not part of the code of the various exception classes, it is only a convention defined by the language, that compilers must implement to be compliant.

Comment: To build on what @assylias wrote:  all Java compilers must detect that a `java.lang.RuntimeException` is in use, and do whatever they need to do internally to flip from "checked" over to "unchecked".  The source code doesn't get to tell the compiler "I'm an unchecked exception," it's that the compiler knows the full name of the RuntimeException class and can look for them.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it extends `RuntimeException` is enough. During compile-time, it knows what the class hierarchy is, so if it includes `RuntimeException`, it's unchecked. Otherwise, it's checked. Remember that checked/unchecked is a compiler constraint, not a runtime constraint, there are ways to make Java throw checked exceptions that are never caught. For example, using `Proxy`:

```
public class ExceptionalInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        throw new IOException("Take that, checked exceptions!");
    }
}
```

And an interface:

```
public interface Example {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

And create a proxy and call it:

```
 Example ex = (Example) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Example.class.getClassLoader(),
     new Class[] { Example.class },
     new ExceptionalInvocationHandler());
 ex.doSomething(); // Throws IOException even though it's not declared.
```

Comment: I knew that it was engough, but how the compiler knows it?

Comment: @DanielPereira Because it has constructed a class hierarchy? If you want the exact implementation details, this isn't the place to ask. Take a look at the compiler source code from OpenJDK.

Comment: Why Stackoverflow is not a place to ask this? I thought it was a programming Q&A site.

Comment: @DanielPereira Because SO is meant to be something that's useful to everyone. Compilers and their implementations are extremely niche. All you need to know as a programmer is that the compiler checks this information using the class hierarchy.

Comment: The last time I check we still needed to use a programming language to develop a compiler, which is enough to ask it here, but nevermind.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), specifically: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." How compilers handle class hierarchies is a very broad question as well. Each compiler will implement it differently, and since there are many JDK implementations, this goes for Java as well.

Comment: @assylias He wants to know how the compiler knows it, not the language specs, otherwise he'd be satisfied, even with my answer. **Edit:** Look at his first comment: "I knew that it was engough, but how the compiler knows it?"

Comment: @Brian His question is completely valid as "is meant to be something that's useful to everyone" is not a requirement. It is useful for some and that is enough. For example, everyone who looks at this question about a week after found it useful as they were researching it. A programmer may want to write a compiler for java for example. He was actually unaware that it was a compiler implementation, and thus validates the question further. The answer to the question is: it is based on the compiler as all compilers are different but follow the java language specifications.